# example of using StingRay SECSplitterBase

Tags: mfc, stingray, rogue-wave

I am interested in a code fragment that demonstrates how to use the Layout Factory and SECSplitter Base (both from StingRay) to deliver a splitter window inside another splitter window.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/stingray/CD50/ObjectiveToolkitUG.pdf ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read pdf provided and have determined I asked the wrong question. What I need is an example of how to use the ADW (from StingRay) to nest docking windows.